# SlowCheetah and TeamCity integration

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, slowcheetah

After discovering SlowCheetah add-on and setup it on my local machine, I faced with problem that TeamCity doesn't run the transformation.

I configured all in the build server according to [this](http://sedodream.com/2012/12/24/SlowCheetahBuildServerSupportUpdated.aspx) article.

I installed the add-on on the build server and run publish from VS 2010 manually.
The transformation is succeeded.
Once TeamCity run the publish, nothing is happens.

Am I missed something? 
How can I recognize the problem when all looks OK?
Is the any log file for transformation process?

I'm using:

- VS 2010 prof
- TeamCity Professional 7.0.2 (build 21349)

Comment: Can you share the MSBuild log?

Comment: You can find the log [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13841056/Deployment_Application_1665.log).
The application name is GRT.DashBoard.Web

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/92 for a solution to this.
The new nuget 2.7.1 should maybe solve this anyways but TeamCity offers a bit more OOB I think. More on the subject found here: http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/making-use-of-teamcitys-nuget-capabilities-part-2/